# Reduce Global Optimisation Search Domain

Tags: optimization

I have an optimisation problem for which the objective function is not differentiable. I am looking for a global optimum using the Simulated Annealing technique in MATLAB. I am facing the problem of a very large search domain. I want to narrow down the search domain before applying Simulated Annealing. Is there a method to reduce the search domain before I apply Simulated Annealing?

Comment: Not differentiable does not say much. $|x|$ is not differentiable but is trivial to minimize.

Comment: The objective function is a CFD code

Comment: and the constraints, which this question really is about?

Comment: The variables are range bound. No linear or non-linear constraints.

Comment: OK. Range bounds does not give you much to do. The general theory you are looking for is bound or constraint propagation in global optimization.

Comment: All right. Is there any text, article, or document I can refer to for further understanding?

Comment: Just a random article with the correct key-words https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.08601.pdf